# Gap at bottom of jumbo-tron cant remove

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the jumbo tron to show an hero image of  psd however there appears to be a gap at the bottom I have tried using margin-bottom:0px but that did not work.

```css
.jumbotron
{

    background-image: url(image/background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size:cover;
    -moz-background-size:cover;
    background-size: cover;
    padding: none !important;
    padding-bottom:none !important;
  margin-bottom: 0; 

}
```

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="Brand">Dipped</div>
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


 <div class="jumbotron">
     <div class="jumpbotron-inner text-center">
  <h1>We build well desgined websites</h1>
  <p>Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra.</p>
  <p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
      Get Started
    </a>

      <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
    Learn More
    </a>

  </p>
           <img src="image/browser.png">
     </div>
</div>



    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

But as you see there is a big margin between the browser image and the bottom of the jumobo tron.

I am suing bootstrap 3.3.7 for reference

Comment: Its looks like that "gap" is coming from 2 places:

1) The margin from the <p> containing the buttons.
2) The default padding on the jumbotron
   - to over write this use "0px" rather than none;

Answer (score 0):

Try these messing with these changes

```
<span>
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
  Get Started
</a>

  <a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
Learn More
</a>
</span>

.jumbotron
```

{

```
background-image: url(image/background.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
background-size: cover;
padding-bottom: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
```

}